# Non-exhaustive patterns error when defining foldr variant

Tags: haskell, fold, non-exhaustive-patterns

I was asked to make a function that works like `foldr` but with *non empty* lists, that works like this: `foldr1 f [x1,x2...xn] = f x1 (f x2...(f xn-1 xn)...)`.

So I defined it like this:

```
foldr1 f [x] = x
foldr1 f (x:xs) = f x (foldr1 f xs)
foldr1 f _ = undefined
```

And I'm still getting "Non-exhaustive patterns in function foldr1" error, despite covering all possibilities. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I agree that it looks like you've covered all the possible cases - but isn't this exactly what `foldr1` does anyway? (PS isn't the "non-exhaustive patterns" error a runtime error rather than a compile-time one? If so, what input are you giving it when you get the error?)

Comment: Yeah, just checked and learned that foldr1 is actually an existing function. This was part of an old exam question I'm doing for practice. The input I was trying is foldr1 (+) [1,2,3,4]

Comment: How are you running this? Are you using GHCi? Are you loading this in a file or typing it in directly? I cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: @AJFarmar I bet that is it! good catch. you should make it an answer. (or maybe find a duplicate...?) closed it. :)

Comment: Running this on WinGHCi